# 4k resolution on xenial

Tags: drivers, 16.04, display, display-resolution

I'm using a NUC5i5RYK (which comes with an Intel 6000 graphics) and Ubuntu Xenial 16.04.

Today I purchased a 4K TV which is connected via the display port on nuc, and by the spec it must support 4K@60p.
But I can only get the 1920x1080 resolution.

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1050mm x 590mm
   1920x1080     60.00*   50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88
....
```

first of all, my DP1 seems to be disconnected (why?). and HDMI2 is delivering the output (what is it?).

I've tried to add a new mode to xrandr but no success:

```
$ gtf 3840 2160 30.00

  # 3840x2160 @ 30.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 65.91 kHz; pclk: 339.57 MHz
  Modeline "3840x2160_30.00"  339.57  3840 4080 4496 5152  2160 2161 2164 2197  -HSync +Vsync

$ xrandr --newmode "3840x2160_30.00"  339.57  3840 4080 4496 5152  2160 2161 2164 2197  -HSync +Vsync
$ xrandr --addmode DP1 3840x2160_30.00
$ xrandr --output DP1 --mode 3840x2160_30.00
xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed
```

Using the System Settings > Displays to force the mode, makes the whole thing to freak out! The monitor shows only a quarter of the screen and the mouse seems lost the position.

By the way it seems that Intel has not yet released a proper driver for xenial. Am I right?

Comment: Is your cable a DP1.2 cable? Does the TV properly support DP1.2? Are you sure you connected via DP? I have a 4K monitor here, and it works fine @30Hz full resolution on both Intel and AMD graphics. However, my CPU is a Haswell (4790S), not Sky Lake, which is the 6xxx series CPUs. I'm not sure how well the 4.4 kernel and Xorg in Xenial support Sky Lake. I've not been able to configure 60Hz in a reliable or acceptable manner for 4K though, on any graphics chipset, including NVidia.

Comment: I'm using a "Prolink mini DP to HDMI" which must work OK. Well, I guess it's an issue with Xenial itself. I think Xorg is now deprecated in Xenial.

Comment: Xorg is certainly not deprecated in Xenial. I don't know where you would have gotten such an idea. And if you're using a mini-DP to HDMI adapter, it is not going to give you 4K@60Hz. You must use DisplayPort 1.2 for it. Not sure about the board and TV, but HDMI 1.4 might be an option too. However, an adapter is most likely not going to support both, which would be required to use 4K.

Comment: Yes, Xorg is not deprecated. The fglrx driver is now deprecated and the xorg.conf is removed. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes . The vendor assures the 4k@60p and 3D on this cable and the device supports 4K@60p on DP and 4K@30p on HDMI. I cannot see 4K on either of them. There is a open source default driver instead of fglrx and the intel driver installer has not been released for the xenial yet. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Which version are you using? wily? May be I have to downgrade?

Comment: Why are you talking about fglrx? Are you using Intel video or have you added an AMD card to the NUC? Try getting a real DP 1.2 cable. What cable exactly are you using? Downgrading to 15.10 won't help, and 15.10 will be End of Life in a couple weeks anyway.

Comment: You were right... I've confused everything. Used another cable with the mini HDMI port and now 4K@30p is working. So I'll change the DP adapter. Thanks @dobey.